# Why the Ticker on InteractiveBrokers have totally different values that in Degiro?

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-exchanges, interactive-brokers

I am trying to replicate my Degiro portfolio in InteractiveBrokers

```
Produkt           Symbol/ISIN   Ticker Symbol  Exchange Symbol
ISHARES EUROPE    IE00B1YZSC51  IMEU           EAM
ISHR PAC XJPN A   IE00B52MJY50  CPXJ           EAM
VANGUARD FTSE EM  IE00B3VVMM84  VFEM           EAM
VANGUARD S&P500   IE00B3XXRP09  VUSA           EAM
```

But when I search by ISIN in InteractiveBrokers the number of the Ticker are totally different than in Degiro:

[image]

Comment: It appears that these ETFs trade on multiple stock exchanges, and in different currencies.

Comment: If your Degiro portfolio consists of securities that trade on exchanges in other countries then the CUSIPs and symbols should be different.

Comment: In Europe they do not use CUSIPs (they are generally only used in North America) but instead use  ISINs, and while CUSIPS can be a subset of ISINs it is possible for a security trading in two different currencies to have the same ISIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible for the same security to trade on multiple exchanges with different currencies.  For example, the Vanguard FTSE EM trades on:

- the London Stock Exchange in US Dollars and British Pounds ("VDEM","VFEM"),
- the Frankfurt Stock Exchange in Euro ("VFEM"),
- the Swiss Exchange in Swiss Francs ("VFEM") and
- the Mexican exchange in Mexican Peso ("VDEMN").

Your Degiro ticker is showing the price in Euro while the IB ticker is showing the price in USD.

Comment: I see a pattern there, you are right about the currencies, looks like Degiro is in Euros and IB is in pounds (some of them multiplied by 100 :?)

Comment: UK tickers are typically priced in pence rather than pounds (hence the 100x multiplier)